# Linear regression using a list of function

Tags: r, regression

I've a dataset with X and Y value obtained from a calibration and I have to interpolate them with a predefined list of polynomial functions and choose the one with the best R2.
The most silly function should be

```
try<-function(X,Y){
   f1<- x + I(x^2.0) - I(x^3.0)
   f2<- x + I(x^1.5) - I(x^3.0)
   ...
   f20<- I(x^2.0) - I(x^2.5) + I(x^0.5)

   r1<- lm(y~f1)
   r2<- lm(y~f2)
   ...
   r20<-lm(y~f20)

   v1<-summary(r1)$r.squared
   v2<-summary(r2)$r.squared
   ...
   v20<-summary(r20)$r.squared

   v<-c(v1,v2,...,v20)
   return(v)
  }
```

I'd like then to make this function shorter and smarter (especially from the definition of r1 to the end). I'd also like to give the user the possibility to choose a function among f1 to f20 (typing the desired row number of *v*) and see the output of the function *print* and *plot* on it.

Please, could you help me?
Thank you.

@mso: the idea of using sapply is nice but unfortunately in this way I don't use a polynome for the regression: my x vector is transformed in the f1 vector according to the formula and then used for the regression. I obtain just one parameter instead of 3 (in this case).

Comment: There's more to life than the best R^2, so be careful accepting this as the best approach.

Comment: Yeah, I know and I think that's even more true when comparing polynomial functions of different degree, as in this case. Unfortunately, who asked me to write the script didn't agree...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create F as a list and proceed:

```
F = list(f1, f2, ...., f20)
r = sapply(F, function(x) lm(y~x))
v = sapply(r, function(x) summary(x)$r.squared)
return v
```

sapply will take each element of F and perform lm with y and put results in vector r. In next line, sapply will take every element of r and get summary and put the results in the vector v. Hopefully, it should work. You could also try lapply (instead of sapply) which is very similar.